# Webextension Firefox alarm not firing

Tags: javascript, alarm, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm new to writing add-ons. I'm trying to get a function to run X minutes after pressing a button. I'm following [this MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/alarms), and comparing to [this example addon](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/blob/master/chill-out/background.js), but can't see my mistake.

So far I have an `example.js` which looks like:

```
var ok = document.createElement('button');
var okText = document.createTextNode("OK");
ok.appendChild(okText);  
ok.onclick = startTimer; 
document.body.appendChild(ok)          

function startTimer(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('click!')  
    browser.alarms.clearAll();
    browser.alarms.create("Remind", {delayInMinutes: 1});
    return false;        
}                        

browser.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(ring);                                                                                                                                                                                         

function ring(alarmInfo) {
    console.log("RING!");
}
```

So far I get the "click" notification in the log, but the "RING!" never happens, whereas I'd expect to see it appear after 1 minute.

---

Some more info, as per comments:
I've written an addon and am running it by running `web-ext run` in the add-on's directory. The `manifest.json` is:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2, 
"name": "Example",
"version": "0.1",
"description": "Example",
 "icons": {
 "48": "icons/example-48.png",
 "96": "icons/example-96.png"   },
 "content_scripts": [
   {
   "matches": ["*://*.google.com/*"],
   "js": ["example.js"],
   "css": ["example.css"]
    }   ],
 "permissions": ["alarms"],
   "run_at": "document_start"   
}
```

The browser console shows a bunch of output from the site I'm on (here google.com) and the only output from example.js is `click!   example.js:57:2`

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this usually means that you need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: What, *exactly*, was shown in the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (Ctrl-Shift-J, or Cmd-Shift-J on OSX) when you tried to install and use the extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that content scripts don't have access to as many APIs as background scripts do (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts). Specifically, they can't access the `alarm` API.

They can, however, use `setTimeout` or `setDelay`, or send a message to a separate background script to deal with the alarms.